# Statements in prenex normal form.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Put these statements in prenex normal form.

a) $\exists x \ P(x) \vee \exists x \ Q(x) \vee A$, $\textit{where A is a proposition not involving any quantifiers.}$

b) $\neg (\forall x \ P(x) \vee \forall x \ Q(x))$

c) $\exists x \ P(x) \rightarrow \exists x \ Q(x)$

I just need a hint.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_passage_%28logic%29

Comment: (b) is the same as $neg(\forall x\,P(x)\vee\forall y\,Q(y))$. (The latter form is called an "alphabetic variant" of the former.)  Sometimes viewing it that way is useful. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Okay this is hard I need more help to do this assignment

Answer (score 0):

a)

$$\exists x  ( P(x) \lor Q(x) \lor A)$$

b) 
Distribute the NOT Operation
$$ \exists  x \lnot P(x)  \land \exists x  \lnot Q(x)  $$

$\exists$  quantifier is not distributed over AND operation, thus we rename

$$ \exists  x \lnot P(x)  \land \exists y  \lnot Q(y)  $$

$$ \exists x   \exists y  (\lnot P(x)  \land \lnot Q(y))  $$

c) Simplify the formula

$$ \lnot(\exists x P(x)) \lor (\exists x Q(x))  $$
$$( \forall x \lnot P(x) ) \lor (\exists x Q(x))$$

Rename one of the variable

$$( \forall x \lnot P(x) ) \lor (\exists z Q(z))$$

$$ \forall x \exists z (\lnot P(x)   \lor Q(z)) $$